# How can I edit a message on Discord into being a reply?

Tags: discord

I've realised that a message that I made in a chat last week should have been a reply to another message. This now breaks the reply chain.

I've clicked on the edit button, but I see no option to change the message to being a reply.

I don't want to delete and repost the message, because it's a week old.

How can I remedy this in the desktop version of Discord?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible.

Comment: @SaaranshGarg If you've got any evidence to support that, such as a popular feature request page for it, then I'll happily accept that as an answer.

Comment: [add reply to edit message – Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360052496353-add-reply-to-edit-message)

Comment: [Be able to edit who you replied to. – Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360052487633-Be-able-to-edit-who-you-replied-to-)

Comment: [Allow inline replies to be a added in when editing a message – Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360051317694-Allow-inline-replies-to-be-a-added-in-when-editing-a-message)

Comment: @DavidPostill That's an answer then. Just say it's impossible, link those as proof, and you're done.

Comment: @J.Mini Done...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I've clicked on the edit button, but I see no option to change the message to being a reply.

It's not currently possible but it has been requested:

[add reply to edit message – Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360052496353-add-reply-to-edit-message)

[Be able to edit who you replied to. – Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360052487633-Be-able-to-edit-who-you-replied-to-)

[Allow inline replies to be a added in when editing a message – Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360051317694-Allow-inline-replies-to-be-a-added-in-when-editing-a-message)

Note that threaded discussions are a relatively recent addition to Discord:

> **Discord finally adds threaded messaging**
>
> Community channels can enable the feature starting today.

Where **today** was **July 27th, 2021**.

Source: [Discord finally adds threaded messaging | Engadget](https://www.engadget.com/discord-threads-150018618.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAEBu3FTl28RPZLYn5N2L9IF6qBAJ_stmyW6XbJRW4SnlTm4cMoTfoILmDFsSBRyYYDBKkObtnoBdeIymFumMKDUjZuHEIpAgjOvbwkcnirngKCBHdTdvEXIEDGBgzWDDaj8fl454pJ00GF4LHJLsUQzIUcEVp7Y1w284yr7cV-Iw)